# VM Shared Folder

Tags: command-line

I am trying to use Ubuntu in a virtual machine on my windows computer. I am trying to set up a shared folder. When I put in the command `sudo adduser carl vboxsf` in terminal it asks for my password. When I try to type it in, it won't accept any input from the keyboard. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not that it is not accepting input, it's that ubuntu does not display any characters when asking for the password to use a sudo command.